# Conditionally compile endpoint based on appsetting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, .net-5, asp.net5

I have a controller that needs to be compiled based on an appsetting. If the appsetting is set to "CompileEndpoint":"true" then the endpoint will be compiled and displayed on swagger page.

the other alternative is to hide the action from swagger based on the app setting, I can return a 404 based on the appsetting if the action is called.

Thank you

Comment: An app setting... in the appsettings.json?  You can't recompile during runtime, unless there's some deep magic that I have not yet experienced.  I think you're left with hiding the action during runtime based on the setting.  Alternatively you could set up your build to read a config file, or use a CI product like DevOps Server, Jenkins, TeamCity, Bamboo, etc where you can set build variables.

Comment: Could you use `Conditional` attribute or `#if #endif` instead? I have exactly this problem in one of my upcoming projects and those are the solutions I thought of. Or look at how to implement feature flags.